# How frequently do GitHub run git-gc on repositories?

Tags: github

Assuming that GitHub occasionally run [git-gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) how frequently does this occur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub Support [responded to this question](https://twitter.com/githubhelp/status/387926738161774592?lang=en) on Twitter in 2013.

> We run `git gc` at most once per day, triggered automatically by a push.

Comment: So, "at most"  ... but it does not explain. One could infer that it's run once per push in a 24 hr period, but still not explicit. And what about now, 7 years later and post-acquisition?

Comment: It's not as precise an answer as I'd like but unless you know better it's as good as they've ever communicated. The answer isn't incorrect, isn't misleading and has value. If any of those things weren't true I'd happily remove the answer.

Answer (score 1):

just tested that a new commit push won't trigger the gc process