# to what extent does using squash or fixup successfully scrub data from github?

Tags: git, github

Suppose we have a commit history like this

```
890xxx more code changes
567zzz delete private data
345cab commit with private data
123abc init commit
```

If I squash or fixup this to

```
890xxx more code changes
123abc init commit
```

I have "scrubbed" the data right? could a future user that has cloned this repo get the data accidentally committed in `345cab`?

(I do realize that the data was still exposed when it was pushed, and that  gh's servers still have it somewhere)

Comment: Run `git clone --mirror url/to/foo.git && git --git-dir=foo.git for-each-ref --contains 345cab`. If it prints at least one ref, the data is still available from these refs.

Comment: Note that, despite not being reachable from any ref, the commit will be around for a while and someone thoroughly investigating your repository might find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a small note to make it clear. After you squashed, the parent of `more code changes` changes to `init commit` so its hash is no longer `890xxx`. But I'm well aware that you just copied the hash for illustration purpose.

To answer your question. As you said, you successfully pushed the change to the server. Thus in the server, those scrubbed commits are longer *reachable* from the tip that is currently pointing to `more code changes`. I assume that tip is named `master`.

Now here is the point of your concern: please double check that, in the server, whether those two scrubbed commits are still *reachable* from any tips other than `master`.

If the answer is no, than those two commits are considered "abandoned" / "not in use" hence will be deleted from the server's repo at *some time*.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020314/how-frequently-do-github-run-git-gc-on-repositories), that "some time" happens at most once per day, triggered automatically by a push.

Comment: When I do a fresh clone somewhere else, I cant reach any secret exposing tips. any ideas for doing this on the server?